# Transformer based digital isolator vs Capacitor based digital isolator

Tags: digital-isolator

Nowadays, digital isolator vendors all argue digital isolators are more superior to optocouplers. And they also argue their product is more superior to others in some aspect. Like TI (produce isolators based on transformer) and ADI (provide isolators based on capacitor), in their appnotes or data sheets, they even compare their products directly with the products come from their competitor. These comparison confused me some. So, anyone can give a comparison fairly and objectively? Or in what situations we must choose one and abandon the other.

Update:

TI says their products have better Magnetic-Field Immunity, and ADI says their products have better CMTI. Anyone has experienced the differences?

Comment: Optocouplers are cheaper. Or what are the properties that you care about?

Comment: Yes, but Optos may degrade by time. And digital isolators can be driven more easier.

Comment: Please see https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask.